# Speeding up recoding of a character column in R

Tags: r

I have some data where each data point is associated with a character vector of varying length. For example, it might be generated by the following function:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(27)

generate_keyset <- function(...) {
  sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = rpois(n = 1, lambda = 10), replace = TRUE)
}

generate_keyset()
#>  [1] "A" "C" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "E" "C" "C" "A" "D" "A" "D" "C" "A"
```

I would like to summarize this keyset by converting it to a single number score. The way this works is straightforward: each key in the keyset has a value, and to get the value of the entire keyset I sum over the values. The key-value map is a tibble with several hundred entries, but you can imagine it looks like:

```
key_value_map <- tribble(
  ~key, ~value,
  "A",       1,
  "B",      -2,
  "C",       8,
  "D",      -4,
  "E",       0
)
```

Currently I am scoring keysets with the following function:

```
score_keyset <- function(keyset) {
  merged_keysets_to_map <- data.frame(
    key = keyset,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ) %>%
    left_join(key_value_map, by = "key")

  sum(merged_keysets_to_map$value)
}

score_keyset(LETTERS[1:4])
#> [1] 3
```

This works fine, except it is very slow, and I need to do this operation about a million times. For example, I would like the following to be much faster:

```
n <- 1e4  # in practice I have n = 1e6

fake_data <- tibble(
  keyset = map(1:n, generate_keyset)
)

library(tictoc)

tic()

scored_data <- fake_data %>%
  mutate(
    value = map_dbl(keyset, score_keyset)
  )

toc()
```

I am sure this is some much better way to do this with indexing but it is escaping me at the moment. Help speeding this up is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a join and then sum, it would be more efficient if we use a named vector to match

```
library(tibble)
sum(deframe(key_value_map)[generate_keyset()])
```

---

Checking the timings, the OP's tic/toc showed `45.728 sec`

```
tic()
v1 <- deframe(key_value_map)

scored_data2 <- fake_data %>%
  mutate(
    value = map_dbl(keyset, ~ sum(v1[.x]))
  )

toc()
#0.952 sec elapsed

identical(scored_data, scored_data2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A nice approach. I was thinking about a solution with `tabulate`, but this way there's much less conversions and no dot products...